# Initialize structure

Tags: vb.net, structure

```
Public Enum eSourceMode
    AUS = 0 
    EIN = 1 
End Enum


Public Structure tSourceChannel

    Dim OnOff() As eSourceMode
    Dim chan_nr As Short 

End Structure
```

I'm trying to set value to

```
        For i = gSources.GetLowerBound(0) To gSources.GetUpperBound(0) Step 1
        gSources(i).chan_nr = i
        'gSources is 0 based ?
        If gSources.GetLowerBound(0) = 0 Then
            k = i + 1
        Else
            k = i
        End If

        Dim hehe As Integer = gSources.Count

        For j = gNoiseBands.GetLowerBound(0) To gNoiseBands.GetUpperBound(0) Step 1
            'ab 17.1.2012: gNrSources sets nr of available outputs
            If k <= gNrSources Then
                gSources(i).OnOff(j) = eSourceMode.EIN
            Else
                gSources(i).OnOff(j) = eSourceMode.AUS
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

result is exception

> System.NullReferenceException occurred

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I need this, because I have .ini file and these values :

```
"gSources0",1,0,1,1,1,1,1
"gSources1",1,1,1,1,1,1,1
"gSources2",1,1,1,1,1,1,1
"gSources3",1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Result of should be for an example :

```
 gSources(0).OnOff(0) = 1 , gSources(0).OnOff(1) = 0
```

Comment: Please post the code where `gSources` is used.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: when i'm trying to set gSources(0).OnOff(0) = eSourceMode.EIN in loop

Comment: You will need to resize the OnOff array before assigning values to it.  Or you could make the structure a class and explicitly declare the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you declare that `OnOff` is an array

```
Dim OnOff() As eSourceMode
```

but you never define how large the array should be or assign memory to the array.

```
'...
Dim hehe As Integer = gSources.Count
'Specify array size
Redim gSources(i).OnOff(gNoiseBands.GetUpperBound(0) -  gNoiseBands.GetLowerBound(0))
For j = gNoiseBands.GetLowerBound(0) To gNoiseBands.GetUpperBound(0) Step 1
    '...
Next j
```